# How to Handle Dynamic path in jmeter

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, performance

How to handle Dynamic Request URL Path in Jmeter. This request is not recorded in Script, it dynamically appears only in Login page response where in two places.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have to use the CSS/JQuery Extractor as a post-processor on the login thread group.

It allows you to query the HTML response using CSS Selector, and save it in a variable.

[image]

More info [here](https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/04/13/jmeter-css-jquery-extractor/).

Afterwards, you can access this variable using the `${variable_name}` notation.

[image]

More info [here](http://thatsabug.com/2019/06/21/jmeter_2.html).